# Is there any other way to determine result than throwing dice?

Tags: dice, diceless

I know that you can go full narrative and not use dice at all, but that's not what I'm asking about.
I want to know any other (pseudo)random way to determine the result of action?

My friend suggested drawing cards of deck, but it's just dice mapped to D13/D52.
You could use some random generator, but still, it is just an Dn.

Is there any crafty way, that's not (easily? at least?) mappable to dices, or if we want some randomness in our games we're stuck with those little bastards?

Comment: @mxyzplk [I think closing it as a duplicate of a locked post isn't a good idea](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268072/does-closing-a-question-as-a-duplicate-of-a-locked-one-makes-sense).

Comment: The old one is locked for a reason, in that there are a large number of diceless resolution methods and a question wanting any or all of them is too broad.

Comment: Learning about diceless designs is best done by studying existing examples anyway rather than having people try to explain a few random ones, since there are nearly as many diceless methods as there are diceless RPGs. You can find diceless games to study in RPGGeek's [database of diceless RPGs](http://rpggeek.com/rpgmechanic/2109/diceless-does-not-use-dice-or-other-randomizer).